# 'Can not set language' error on SpaceVim launch

Tags: error, spacevim

I'm a very new vim user and I'm enjoying it, so I've decided to try SpaceVim. But each time I launch vim, I see the error `Can not set language to en_US.utf8`, and vim gives me the option to press  and continue the launch. Everything seams to be working fine, but I'd rather have the error fixed and not need to press the extra key each time I launch vim. I've tried adding the line `let g:spacevim_language = 'en_XX.utf8'` (where 'XX' is my country's ISO code) to the init.vim file, but this seams to have no effect.

Comment: SpaceVim author here，It seems a bug of SpaceVim. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SpaceVim we have a code snippet:

`""
  " set language
  if !empty(g:spacevim_language)
    silent exec 'lan ' . g:spacevim_language
  endif`

so I think you should use a correct value.